# ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter does not refresh after changes

Tags: android, listview, refresh, contacts, simplecursoradapter

I created a kind of contacts application. I am using a ListView and a SimpleCursorAdapter, and the contacts are stored in a SQLite database.

In the main screen, there are two buttons: "Add contacts" and "View contacts". When I view the contacts and I click on one of them, I can edit or delete that contact.

After I do any of these changes, the contacts list displayed should refresh according to the changes made, but it doesn't.

I have read and tried plenty of possible solutions, but every case that I find is different, and apparently some solutions only work in some cases, so I'm very confused.

In the main activity, I call this method:

```
public void viewContacts(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the Contacts class:

```
public class Contacts extends ExampleActivity {

ContactsOpenHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
Cursor c;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contactslayout);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    dbHelper = new ContactsOpenHelper(this);
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {Contract.Entry.NAME,Contract.Entry.NUMBER,_ID};

    c = db.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);

    String[] fromColumns = {Contract.Entry.NAME,Contract.Entry.NUMBER};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.textViewName, R.id.textViewNumber};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.contactslayoutentry,c,fromColumns,toViews,0);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ContactDialog cd = new ContactDialog(db, id, adapter);
            cd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Contactos");
        }
    });

}
}
```

The ContactDialog class:

```
public class ContactDialog extends DialogFragment {

SQLiteDatabase db;
long id;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

public ContactDialog(SQLiteDatabase db, long id, SimpleCursorAdapter adapter) {
    this.db = db;
    this.id = id;
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose an action")
            .setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MyDialogFragment mdf = new MyDialogFragment(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), db, true, id);
                    mdf.show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String selection = Contract.Entry._ID + " LIKE ?";
                    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};
                    db.delete(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

In the MyDialogFragment class I run the line

```
db.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, myValues, Contract.Entry._ID + " LIKE " + id,null);
```

I don't know if I need the **notifySetDataChanged()** method, when to execute it, or whether I need another solution.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I forgot to point out that the elements are correctly edited or deleted in the database. When I do some changes, I go back to the main screen and click on "View contacts" again, and the list is updated. I guess this is important to know.

Comment: you have deleted the record from database but you have not fetched updated records from database again. you will have to do that before you notify your adapter.

Comment: How do I fetch the updated records from the database?

Comment: the contact database is created by your own or system?

Comment: @FireSun I created it myself.

Comment: I added to my question some information I forgot to give, and I guess it's important.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,I suggest you use [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) and [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html),it will be better than your current solution.

If you still want to use this solution,please add cursor.requery() after update your data,like this:

```
db.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, myValues, Contract.Entry._ID + " LIKE " + id,null);
adapter.getCursor().requery();
```

Comment: The **requery()** method is deprecated and my software doesn't allow me to use it.

Comment: I'm changing to CursorLoader and LoaderManager. Just one question: what is the value of the parameter CONTENT_URI in the constructor of CursorLoader in this case?